# What happens to an individual .edu Google Apps account that is taken over by a Google Apps for Education migration?

Tags: google-apps, google-apps-for-education

I currently use my @.edu email address as a Google Apps login, and I have a Google Plus account, Google Docs, a Youtube account, Google Finance, and many other Google Apps products tied to that @.edu account profile.

My university is currently planning on moving it's entire .edu domain and email system to Google Apps for Education. How will this affect my current solo Google Apps profile? I know that domain owners can specify which Google Apps products I could login to. Will my Youtube account and all its content be destroyed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will be given the option on your next login to either:

- Delete your previous account

OR

- Rename the 'old' account to a new email address (e.g. sxflynn@gmail.com)

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what will happen to your solo Apps account once your university moves to Google Apps. But here is a link which may come to rescue you in terms of data at least.

http://www.dataliberation.org/